# Loading an axis Camera in qt with open cv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have been trying for some time to load an image from a axis 205 network cam into my qt programming using opencv running on a windows laptop. According to the cameras configuration page

> The Motion JPEG image stream is fetched from the file:
>   `http://192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480`

the login for the camera is root for the username and pass for the password

I have tried several variations in the code but I can not get the program to display the image

`VideoCapture * cap = new  VideoCapture("http://192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480");`

`Mat frame;`

`cap->read(frame);`

Everything I try results in an empty frame, Thanks for any help

~Gibby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more messing around I discovered that the correct code is

```
    VideoCapture * cap = new  VideoCapture("http://root:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480.mjpg");
```

For whatever reason the url must end in mjpg.